# asp.net Website Project Virtual directories build fail

Tags: teamcity

I have an asp.net Website project (not application) that I run with IIS Express.  Within my applicationhost.config file i have setup several virtual directories that my website needs to run.  Locally the website runs fine.

I need to be able to set virtual directories for Teamcity to be able to build the website successfully.  I have not been able to find out how I can set the multiple virtual directories for team city to handle the build.  Since its a website project I don't have a proj file to set this.

I just want the Virtual directories available for the build process, nothing more since i have the VD setup on the deployment server already.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

I have looked at .build files, not sure if this is the correct route.

Comment: Why is this down voted with no comment?  I thought it was a legitimate question

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of IIS express is that it requires the `application.config` file to be located at the location `Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress\config`.

Have you check that the folder exists for the user running the TeamCity agent service. For example if the user running the build agent service is named `TeamCityAgent` the `application.config` file is located in `Users\TeamCityAgent\Documents\IISExpress\config`.